# npm run script returns "No such file or directory" when trying to bundle files

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to make all our Angular web components use the same build steps in our Bamboo build server. All projects must be built like this:

1. npm install
2. npm run build
3. npm run bundle

`npm run build` works perfectly. It's simply executing this command:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=none --single-bundle
```

This creates a directory called `dist` that includes the following files:

- main-es5.js
- main-es2015.js
- polyfills-es5.js
- polyfills-es2015.js
- scripts.js

I need to bundle the `*-es5.js` and `*-es2015.js` files into their own single file, instead of two files. That is why I call `npm run bundle`, which is this command:

```
cat dist/{polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js > dist/element-es5.js && cat dist/{polyfills-es2015,main-es2015}.js > dist/element-es2015.js
```

However, it seems like it cannot find the files, because I get a

> cat: dist/{polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js: No such file or directory

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I am in the correct directory when I call `npm run bundle`. `dist/` and `package.json` are in the same directory.

If I directly copy the line `cat: dist/{polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js` and paste it into the terminal, all the content of the files gets output to the terminal. It seems like `npm run bundle` isn't being executed from the same path.

What could my problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, looking further into it, it seems like `cat {file1,file2}.js` isn't working properly. It's actually trying to look for a file called `{file1,file2}.js` instead of counting how many files there actually are.

Solved by going with:

```
cat dist/polyfills-es5.js dist/main-es5.js > dist/element-es5.js && cat dist/polyfills-es2015.js dist/main-es2015.js > dist/element-es2015.js
```